# Controller for model in Dymola

Tags: modelica, dymola, openmodelica

I need to control a flow that over time will go down to zero. From Matlab I have constructed a x and y graph where x is time and y is the Q-flow(Heat). What kind of controller could I use for this? I have looked at Ramp or firstorder.

From the picture the red circle is where I want to connect the controller.

[image]

Comment: it seems you don't need a controller, just a boundary condition setting component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Modelica.Blocks.Sources.TimeTable` and `Modelica.Blocks.Sources.CombiTimeTable` should do the trick. You might even be able to copy-paste your x-y array from matlab.

(Personal advice: pay attention to the documentation; only considering the icon, I messed up sometimes the vector index I wanted to connect as the output)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the components in your picture. But if the red circled component adds a prescribed heat to the fluid stream you could simply connect a `Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Ramp` to its `RealInput` connector.

Best regards Rene Just Nielsen